# Find The Roots of A Polynomial Given their Powersums

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, roots

Let $P(x)=\prod_{i=1}^n(x-z_i)=x^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+c_0$, such that
$0 < z_i < 1$. Assuming that we know the root powersums $s_i = \sum_{j=1}^n z_i^j$ we can use the [Newton Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities) to find the coefficients $c_i$ and then solve the polynomial equation $P(x) = 0$ to find the roots $z_i$.

The following systems of Newton Identities can be solved to find the coefficients.
\begin{eqnarray*}
  s_k + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} c_{n-i}s_{k-i} + k c_{n-k} =0, \quad k = 1,2, \ldots,n \\
  s_{n+k} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{n-i}s_{n+k-i} = 0,\quad k=1,2,\ldots,m-n
\end{eqnarray*}
For $m=n$ the system takes the following matrix form, where we omit
zero elements.
\begin{equation*}\label{equation-newton-identities}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    1   &  &  & & \\
    s_1 & 2 &  &  &  \\
    s_2 & s_1 & 3 & \\
    \vdots & \vdots &\ddots & \ddots & \\
    s_{n-1} & s_{n-2} & \dots &  s_1 & n
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    c_{n-1} \\
    c_{n-2} \\
    c_{n-3} \\
    \vdots \\
    c_0
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    - s_{1} \\
    - s_{2} \\
    - s_{3} \\
    \vdots \\
    - s_n
  \end{pmatrix}
  \Leftrightarrow Ax=b
\end{equation*}
For $m>n$ we get the additional $k = m-n$ equations
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    s_n   & s_{n-1} & \ldots & s_2 & s_1 \\
    s_{n+1} & s_n &  \ldots & s_3 & s_2 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots & \vdots\\
    s_{n+k-1} & s_{n+k-2} &\ldots & s_{k+1} & s_{k} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    c_{n-1} \\
    c_{n-2} \\
    \vdots \\
    c_0
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    - s_{n+1} \\
    - s_{n+2} \\
    \vdots \\
    - s_{n+k} \\
  \end{pmatrix}
  \Leftrightarrow Cx=d
\end{equation*}

> **Question**:
>   Is there a way to go from the root powersums $s_i$ directly to the roots $z_i$ without having to solve the polynomial equation $P(x)=0$ ?

Comment: If that were possible then you'd have a method to "directly compute" the roots of an arbitrary polynomial (since you can compute the power sums from the coefficients as well).

Comment: Yes, but I assumed that I know $n$ or even more of the powersums of the roots which distinct this problem from the general case.

Comment: You can compute the coefficients from the power sums *and vice versa.* There  is no difference in the amount of information available.

Comment: Is there any additional information about the roots, which I could assume is known, in order to make finding the roots easier? I already know that the roots are distinct,real, lie in $(0,1)$ and separated by at least a distance $d$.

Comment: I believe this post I've just posted helps you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2520681/newtons-identities-for-finding-polynomial-root

Comment: You can make an *iterative* (altho numerically unstable) algorithm from this, but don't hope for a symbolic solution in general, for reasons mentioned in earlier comments.